# Search phone with wildcard

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to verify if phone is in anrray, but with wildcard.

Inside the foreach I have thw follow code:

```
$phone = '98765432'; // Data of stored phone
$match = '987*5432'; // Input with search term

echo preg_match('/^' . str_replace('*', '.*', $match) . '$/i' , $phone);
```

When I search for one of the follows, `preg_match` should work:

```
9*
987*5432
987*
*876*
```

But, when I search with wrong numbers, for instance, `preg_match` should not work:

```
8*65432
*1*
98*7777
```

I have tried, but can't find the correct solution. Thanks!

EDIT 1

`2*2*` should pass to `2020`, but not to `2002`

Comment: Why would `*7*` not match? Seems like it should.

Comment: @nickb Sorry, it is a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `\d`, like this:

```
preg_match('/^' . str_replace('*', '(\d+)', $match) . '$/i' , $phone);
```

Comment: @GabrielSantos I updated the answer, just use `\d+` instead of `\d*`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to match everything, I would only focus on digits, since you know you're dealing with a phone number:

```
preg_match('/^' . str_replace('*', '\d*', $input) . '$/i' , $phone);
```

I wrote a [simple test case](http://viper-7.com/gjNyCh) that seems to work for your input.

```
$phone = '98765432'; // Data of stored phone

function test( $input, $phone) {
    return preg_match('/^' . str_replace('*', '\d*', $input) . '$/i' , $phone);
}

echo 'Should pass:' . "\n";
foreach( array( '9*', '987*5432', '987*', '*876*') as $input) {
    echo test( $input, $phone) . "\n";
}

echo 'Should fail:' . "\n";
foreach( array( '8*65432', '*1*', '98*7777') as $input) {
    echo test( $input, $phone) . "\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
Should pass:
1
1
1
1
Should fail:
0
0
0
```